# Creating a helper tool to assist in an android application's development process

Tags: java, android, arraylist, dialog, desktop

I'm developing an android application which contains some `ArrayLists` of `Integers` and `Strings` but they will have a `size` of about 500. Currently there are 42 elements in each `ArrayList` and since the process of adding to those `ArrayLists` is the same, i was wondering how i should go about creating a tool(just for me the developer) which will take as input ***the index into which the element should be added, it's value etc***. How can i create such a tool that will add all of the above things to those Lists without having to run the actual app on a phone? Can i write another app that does that and somehow connects to my first app?  Sorry if i didn't describe my problem correctly, i'm having a hard-time explaining this. Any help is welcome!

Comment: So you want a dialog that's only available for developers?

Comment: Do you want a tool that will run on your pc and insert data into your phone app?
where is that data is saved? Is it a DB or only a runtime data?

Comment: @regevavraham yes that's what i'm looking for. The data is saved on the user's intenral storage and it's a database! I want to be able to add data into that dialog and then when i hit 'OK' for example, add that data to those ArrayLists so that the next time the app runs, the new data will be there!